# How to change Authentication MongoDB 3.2

Tags: mongodb, nosql

mongoDB version 2.6 was an option file mongod.conf
Allow "Auth" Or "NoAuth"

[image]

How to do it now mongoDB version 3.2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the Mongo docs here - 
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/configuration-options/#security.authorization - one can enable authorization (which is DISABLED by default) by doing the following:

1. Edit the mongo settings file /etc/mongod.conf
2. Add the line:

> security.authorization : enabled

3. Restart the service

Regards,